# Retirar efeito de elemento filho em CSS

Tags: css, css3

Tenho o seguinte código

```js
   
      $(document).ready(function(e) {

         const blocos = $("div.slider div.slide div");
      
         function startslider() {  
         
            ativa = $(".ativa")
         
            if (!$(ativa).next("div.slide").length) {
               // remove a classe do último
               $(ativa)
               .removeClass("ativa")
         
               // adiciona a classe no primeiro
               $("div.slider div.slide")
               .first()
               .addClass("ativa")
            }else{
               $(ativa)
               .removeClass("ativa")
               .next()
               .addClass("ativa")
            }
         
            setTimeout(startslider, 5000)
         }
         
         setTimeout(startslider, 5000)
         
          $("div.slider nav button.anterior").click(function(){
          
            prev = $(".ativa").prev();  
            prev = prev.length ? prev : blocos[ blocos.length - 1 ];  
            mostraBloco(prev);
            
          })
          
          $("div.slider nav button.proximo").click(function(){
              
            next = $(".ativa").next();   
            next = next.length ? next : blocos.first();    
            mostraBloco(next);
            
          })
          
          /* Função para exibir as imagens */
          function mostraBloco(next) {
              
            ativa = $(".ativa")
            
            $(ativa).removeClass("ativa")
            $(next).addClass("ativa")
            
          }
      
      })
```

```css
      * {
          margin: 0;
          padding: 0;
          border: none;
          outline: 0;
      }
      body {
          width: 100vw;
      }
      ul {
          list-style: none;
      }
      .fade {
          -webkit-animation-name: fade;
          -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
          animation-name: fade;
          animation-duration: 1.5s;
      }
       @-webkit-keyframes fade {
       from {
       opacity: .4
      }
       to {
       opacity: 1
      }
      }
       @keyframes fade {
       from {
       opacity: .4
      }
       to {
       opacity: 1
      }
      }
      @keyframes slider {
       0% {
       transform: scale(1);
      }
       100% {
       transform: scale(1.1);
      }
      }
      div.slider {
          position: relative;
          width: 100%;
          overflow: hidden;
      }
      div.slider div.slide {
          display: none;
      }
      .ativa {
          display: block !important;
          animation: fade 1s linear;
      }
      div.slider div.slide img {
          position: relative;
          width: 100%;
          animation: slider 1s linear;
          animation-fill-mode: forwards;
      }
      div.slider div.slide span {
          position: absolute;
          width: 100px;
          left: calc(50% - 50px);
          line-height: 40px;
          bottom: 0;
          text-align: center;
          color: rgb(255,255,255);
          z-index: 2;
      }
      div.slider nav {
          position: absolute;
          width: 100%;
          height: 40px;
          bottom: 0;
          background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
          z-index: 1;
      }
      div.slider nav button {
          position: absolute;
          width: 150px;
          height: 100%;
          cursor: pointer;
      }
      div.slider nav button.anterior {
          left: 10%;
      }
      div.slider nav button.proximo {
          right: 10%;
      }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <div class="slider">
    
     <div class="slide ativa">
       <img src="_img/_banner/_site/bg_1.jpg" />
       <span>Este é 1</span>
     </div>
     
     <div class="slide">
       <img src="_img/_banner/_site/bg_2.jpg" />
       <span>Este é 2</span>
     </div>
    
     
     <div class="slide">
       <img src="_img/_banner/_site/bg_3.jpg" />
       <span>Este é 3</span>
     </div>
    
     <nav>
      <button class="anterior">Anterior</button>
      <button class="proximo">Próximo</button>
     </nav>
    
    </div>
```

Tem a **tag span** dentro de cada `div.slide` que está herdando a animação que seu **container** (`div.slide`) está recebendo que é um `.fade`.

Preciso retirar esse **efeito** apenas do `span`.

Será que tem jeito?

Comment: Carlos só com esse trecho de  código fica complicado de dar uma resposta exata. Coloque o código completo com CSS e JS do slider também

Comment: ok, alterado lá. coloquei o código todo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode remover o efeito da `div`e colocá-lo na imagem porque assim o efeito não inclui o `span`.

Eu precisei fazer algumas modificações que citei abaixo no CSS e jQuery para conseguir fazer funcionar.

Um leve efeito que ainda é visível na letra é devido a opacidade da imagem, que aparece por trás da letra, estar sendo alterada.

```js
    $(document).ready(function (e) {
    const blocos = $("div.slider div.slide"); /* REMOVIDO ' div'*/

    function startslider() {
        ativa = $(".ativa")

        if (!$(ativa).next("div.slide").length) {
            // remove a classe do último
            $(ativa)
                .removeClass("ativa")

            // adiciona a classe no primeiro
            $("div.slider div.slide")
                .first()
                .addClass("ativa")
        } else {
            $(ativa)
                .removeClass("ativa")
                .next()
                .addClass("ativa")
        }

        setTimeout(startslider, 5000)
    }

    setTimeout(startslider, 5000)

    $("div.slider nav button.anterior").click(function () {

        prev = $(".ativa").prev();
        prev = prev.length ? prev : blocos[blocos.length - 1];
        mostraBloco(prev);

    })

    $("div.slider nav button.proximo").click(function () {

        next = $(".ativa").next(".slide"); /* Add .slide */

        next = next.length ? next : blocos.first();
        mostraBloco(next);

    })

    /* Função para exibir as imagens */
    function mostraBloco(next) {

        ativa = $(".ativa")

        $(ativa).removeClass("ativa")
        $(next).addClass("ativa")

    }

})
```

```css
/* .fade {
    -webkit-animation-name: fade;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1.5s;
    animation-name: fade;
    animation-duration: 1.5s;
} */
@-webkit-keyframes fade {
    from {
    opacity: .4
    }
    to {
    opacity: 1
    }
}
@keyframes fade {
    from {
    opacity: .4
    }
    to {
    opacity: 1
    }
}
@keyframes slider {
    0% {
    transform: scale(1);
    }
    100% {
    transform: scale(1.1);
    }
}

div.slider {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

div.slider div.slide:not(.ativa) { /* As divs que não contém a classe .ativa*/
    display: none;
}

.ativa {
    display: block !important;
    /* animation: fade 1s linear; */ /* efeito REMOVIDO*/
}
div.slider div.slide img {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    animation: slider 5s linear, fade 2s linear running; /* Adiciona múltiplos efeitos às imagens */
    animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
div.slider div.slide span {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100px;
    left: calc(50% - 50px);
    line-height: 40px;
    bottom: 0;
    text-align: center;
    color: rgb(255,255,255);
    z-index: 2;
}
div.slider nav {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    bottom: 0;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    z-index: 1;
}
div.slider nav button {
    position: absolute;
    width: 150px;
    height: 100%;
    cursor: pointer;
}
div.slider nav button.anterior {
    left: 10%;
}
div.slider nav button.proximo {
    right: 10%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Page Title</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="fade.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <div class="slider">
        <div class="slide ativa">
            <img src="https://s19.postimg.cc/4khrr69kz/img_1.png" />
            <span class="not-fade">Este é 1</span>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://s19.postimg.cc/jggays0f7/img_2.png" />
            <span class="not-fade">Este é 2</span>
        </div>
        <div class="slide">
            <img src="https://s19.postimg.cc/kvhvnhtsj/img_3.png" />
            <span class="not-fade">Este é 3</span>
        </div>
    
        <nav>
            <button class="anterior">Anterior</button>
            <button class="proximo">Próximo</button>
        </nav>
    
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

***Off-topic***: É uma boa prática declarar variáveis Javascript explicitando a *keyword* `var`, pois assim a variável será uma **local**, ou seja, presente apenas dentro daquele escopo. Caso contrário, ela será criada no escopo **global** (objeto mais global que em *client side* é a janela - `window`). Em programas menores isso pode não ser um grande problema, mas quando seu programa começa 
a crescer, isso pode causar inconsistências. Além disso, a memória ocupada pode crescer rapidamente tornando a página mais lenta principalmente em dispositivos com menos memória RAM.

---

### EDIÇÃO

Como apontado por @Carlos Rocha, a imagem só estava recebendo um efeito.
Para corrigir esse problema, basta adicioná-los juntos na propriedade `animation`.

```
 animation: slider 5s linear, fade 2s linear running;
```

É possível, inclusive, adicionar mais de um efeito.

```
animation: slider 5s linear, fade 2s linear, color-animation 3s linear running;
```

onde `color-animation` poderia ser, por exemplo

```
@keyframes color-animation {
    from { filter:  grayscale(80%); }
    to   { filter:  grayscale(0%); }
}
```

Mais um tópico fora da questão: se você estiver buscando compatibilidade entre os browsers, é uma boa ideia incluir prefixos *vendor* em `@keyframes` e `animation` para cada kit/browser. Talvez você até já tenha mas não incluiu pra simplificar a pergunta mas abaixo está uma lista com os prefixos *vendor* retirados da [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_animation-keyframes.asp) e [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/%40keyframes)

```
@-moz-keyframes identificador    /* Mozilla Firefox */
@-webkit-keyframes identificador /* Safari, Chrome, Opera e algumas versões do Firefox */
@-o-keyframes identificador      /* Algumas versões do Opera */
@keyframes identificador         /* sem vendor */

   -webkit-animation: fade 2s;  /* Safari, Chrome, Opera e algumas versões do Firefox */
      -moz-animation: fade 2s;  /* Mozilla Firefox */

        -o-animation: fade 2s;  /* Algumas versões do Opera */
           animation: fade 2s;  /* sem vendor */
```

Comment: então, eu estava tendo esse problema antes de postar a pergunta.
Pois a div não está aceitando dois efeitos: o de aumentar a imagem e do fader ao mesmo tempo. Só consegui juntar os dois efeitos depois que joguei um deles para a div. Veja que o teu código não dá efeito de crecsimento da imagem

Comment: É verdade. Não havia notado. Atualizei agora com os dois efeitos funcionando. Tem um assunto que não inclui na resposta que é caso de dois efeitos diferentes usarem a mesma propriedade CSS - `filter` por exemplo. Então a solução mais prática será adicionar apenas a imagem dentro de uma `div` e adicionar um efeito à `div` e outro efeito à `img`.

Comment: sabe o que o cansaço é capaz de fazer com a gente? kkk. Você está corretíssimo na sua perfeita explicação. Eu fiz o mesmo slide de 3 formas diferentes. 2 com JavaScript e 1 com JS puro. Segue os links:
http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/index2.php, http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/index3.php, http://funerariasaopedro.net.br/novo/index4.php, 
Muito, mas muito obrigado pelo apoio. Agora é estilizar as setinhas, os textos e fazer as media queries. O que eu não quero é usar pligins. Dá trabalho... mas é só uma vez